# String representation of file name

Tags: python, argparse

I have a script that uses argparse to handle command line arguments. One argument can be stdin or a file name. The basic code looks like this:

```
import argparse

p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument('--input', type=argparse.FileType('r'), default='-')
args = p.parse_args()

for line in args.input:
    print line
```

In another section of code, I need a string representation of this file name. How can I get a string of this file name. I was trying something like this, without success:

```
 str(args.input)
 repr(args.input)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`.name` attribute](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.name) of the file object:

```
args.input.name
```

This is the filename of the open fileobject, or `<stdin>` for `sys.stdin`.